# Python error when running from file but not from prompt

Tags: python

I have just installed Python 3.4.0 on Windows. PATH is set properly, the trailing slash in C:\Python34\ removed, but I am having trooble running some scripts from an external file.

For example, I have found a hello world script for Tkinter. For argument, the simplest version is:

```
import tkinter
root = tkinter.Tk()
```

If I run each line individually in the prompt, it runs fine and it opens the window. If I save it in a file and try to run "python my_file.py" in the prompt, I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Tk'
```

in line 2. I get strange errors trying to do stuff like

```
from tkinter.constants import *
```

or even

```
import sys
```

but only when I run from a file. Stuff like

```
print("Hello world")
```

runs just fine either way, so I think PATH is doing fine. What gives?

Comment: What are the "strange errors" you're getting? Please [edit] your question to include as much info as possible.

Comment: Also, the standard question when people get mysterious `AttributeError`s: did you happen to name a program of your own `tkinter.py`?  You can check by doing `import tkinter` and then `print(tkinter.__file__)`.

Comment: I was gonna edit and include more detail, but then I read @DSM 's response and that was it. Thank you both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have a local file named "tkinter.py" that is getting imported when you do "import tkinter". You can verify that pretty easily with the following:

```
import tkinter
print(tkinter.__file__)
```

Comment: Yes, that was it, as DSM pointed out above. It was the name of the helloworld script